# Using php foreach to get a second JSON Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a nested array from a json API that usually have zero, one, or two arrays.

I can get it so if the array is empty to display "N/A", and to display only the first ([0]) instance of the array.

However displaying the second array is tripping me up. I know I need to use the foreach to iterate through the **PosTags** (see below) array, so to extract each **Tag** value in the body of the foreach loop. However, I can't figure HOW to do this correctly.

My JSON:

```
[
    {
    "SectionDetails": [
            {
                "Description": "Course Description",
                "Departments": "Department",
                "Credits": "3.00",
                "Meetings": [
                    {
                        "DOW": "Th",
                        "Dates": "08-31-2017 to 12-08-2017",
                        "Times": "03:00 PM - 05:30 PM",
                    }
                ],
                "PosTags": [
                    {
                        "Tag": "HART-ANC"
                    },
                    {
                        "Tag": "ARCH-ARCH"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Current PHP:

```
$postag = "N/A";
if (isset($sectiondetails->{'PosTags'})) 
    {
        if(!empty($sectiondetails->{'PosTags'})) {
            $postag=$sectiondetails->{'PosTags'}[0]->{'Tag'};
        }
    }
```

Running a foreach loop like the following displays "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" on the line where `echo tag` is:

```
if (isset($sectiondetails->{'PosTags'})) {
     if(!empty($sectiondetails->{'PosTags'})) {
        $postag=$sectiondetails->{'PosTags'};
        foreach ($postag as $tag) {
           echo $tag;
        }
     }
}
```

Ideally I'd like HART-ANC, ARCH-ARCH to be displayed. Thoughts?

Comment: Try `echo $tag->{'Tag'};` there instead of `echo $tag;`.

Comment: `SectionDetails` is array of objects. Please __dump__ your variables to see its' structure.

Comment: We can assume his `$sectiondetails` is set correctly, because he stated that he has no trouble showing just one PosTag... its the loop for more is where he got stuck.

Comment: I misread the question. Somehow I thought the first code wasn't working. And the second code should debug it. Deleting my nonsense.

Comment: @Randall adding  `echo $tag->{'Tag'};` does the trick, thanks! 

Follow-up: how can I then store the value(s) of `$tag->{'Tag'}` from that loop so I can echo it later on my html page? Would `foreach ($postag as $tag) {
               $tags = $tag->{'Tag'};
            }` do it?

Comment: Different Q, but its short... you would need to store them into an array, otherwise it would only keep the last one you assigned. So add to array like: `$tags[] = $tag->{'Tag'};`